# Using Stepper Motor like Hobbyist Servo

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, control, servo

I want to use a stepper motor in place of a hobbyist servo that I am currently using to actuate a throttle. The motor is to turn from 0 to 90 and modulate engine speed between these two positions using a PID algorithm implemented on an Arduino Mega microcontroller.

I am having difficulty with the control logic. I have purchased a BigEasyDriver circuit but cannot work out how to get the motor to return to the "0 throttle angle" position upon being reset. The servo was simple to control in this regard - one would simply write servo.write(0) and it would actuate back to the right throttle position. However the stepper does not have an "absolute" starting position?

Can anyone give some advise in this regard? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would need no install a referennce sensor and do the homing procedure each start up. A ref. sensor can be a mechanical or inductive switch located possibly at 0 position.
At start up you begin to move the stepper motor slowly bkw (if the signal isn't present), after the switch is detected you stop and move very slow fwd until the switch looses again. At this point you store the homing position, for ex. 5 or 10 degrees. Then you do movement, you can go to 0 or wherever you want.

EDIT:
One another possibilty is to go slowly bkw for the time the throttle needs to retract from max open position, the motor will come to the hard endstop (you need to provide a hard stop without damage). The motor will stall all the time it will be forced to move further backward. Then after predetermined time you stop and store 0 (or -5, yet better) point.

Comment: A resolver or positional sensor? Or limit switch? Would it work to remember how many steps in a particular direction the stepper moved before shutdown, write to EEPROM memory, and then on start-up move back that same number of steps? there would be no resistance/other movement from the throttle.

Comment: Limit switch, or nothing - hard stop limit. Storing into EEPROM won't help much, you can move throttle by hand or the motor can stall, therefore you have to reposition sometime, the best is to reposition each start up. It's not so difficult, but also if you are using closed loop control PID maybe it's even unecessary, you should describe with more details, and wipe the purchasing info as here are very angry if someone asks about a purchase.